# How to handle (flag) duplicates across stackexchange sites.

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This question on Programmers:
[What is the datastore used by Google for Google Instant?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68601/what-is-the-datastore-used-by-google-for-google-instant)

Is pretty much an exact duplicate of this on on SO: [How does Google Instant work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670831/how-does-google-instant-work)

Quite rightly, the answer to the Programmers question references the SO answer (and althought the answerer on Programmers suggest upvoting on the SO answer a couple of votes were cast on this answer - no problem so long as the original answer also got upvotes).

Clearly these would be merged as duplicates if they were both on one site, but as Anna clarifed to me the other day we do not close questions as duplicates if the dupe is on another SE site.

So, does this imply that one of these questions should actually be migrated, in which case one of them can be closed, or do we expect some questions to meet the FAQs for both sites, and so they would both remain as they are?

What would be the correct flagging here? Should I flag such as a question as attention migration, or should I leave alone if it appears to meet the FAQ?

Comment: Also see this related question http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/what-is-the-current-policy-for-questions-that-are-duplicates-of-stack-overflow

Answer (score 2):

If it belongs on this site, you can just leave it alone. Maybe add a comment saying that other answers are available on SO as you did.

If the SO version ever gets migrated, it'll be merged or closed as a duplicate of the question asked here.

Comment: I guess my point is, should this be a trigger to consider a migration of the SO question?

Comment: @Steve I think it depends on the question. Some are more timeless than others and if the original question is old, it may be good to get some fresh answers instead of falling back on the old ones. There's also a matter of deciding if the question is really on topic here in the first place or if it should stay on SO.

Comment: @Steve So the bottom line is that it's good to know when we have a question that's already been asked on another site and then we can determine what, if anything, should be done about it.